# C# Event invocation list filtering

Tags: c#, events

I have one event in C#. There are five subscribers for that. All the subscribers are different classes. But while raising the event i want that not all the subscriber/handler should be notified to handle this event. I should have some filtering mechanism and then only remaining subscribers should be notified. What could be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Would you mind elaborating how the filter should work? Is it dependant on a "type of message" set beforehand or something that the first subscriber does which invalidates that the event should be triggered to the other listeners (sort of like a "I already took care of this, the rest of you don't have to do anything")?

Comment: Yes it is dependent of type of message. There will be say an Id and based on this I need to invoke only those subscribers concerned with thar Id

Comment: Is this list of id's predetermined? In other words, can you add an event for each of the id's, or is it dynamic in the sense that the list can change during the lifetime of the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it with your existing even then just iterate through the invocation list on the event.

```
var list = localHandler.GetInvocationList();
foreach (EventHandler<T> item in list)
{
    if(((ICanDoThing)item.Target).CanDoThing)
    {
        item(this, someArgs);
    }
 }
```

Now, you can see I've cast item.Target to a type of ICanDoThing, which is an interface I've just made up that exposes a method "CanDoThing". This allows you to query the object for whether it supports your particular need.

You should probably question whether you should use an event anyway for this, but the above will allow you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need multiple events here, so that subscribers can subscribe to the events they really want.

> Subscribing an event means that you are interested in an event. If you
>   are not interested in an event you should not subscribe it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the observer pattern, described here: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx and implement your logic in the update method of the observer.